# bash -c nvm not working

Tags: bash

I have installed `nvm` and it was appended to my `/home/www-data/.bashrc`

Calling `nvm` works.

```
bash
nvm
```

works

but

```
$ bash -c nvm
bash: nvm: command not found
```

does not work.

same when I specific the rcfile

```
$ bash  --rcfile /home/www-data/.bashrc -c "nvm"
bash: nvm: command not found
```

Why is that?

In the end-result I want to use nvm in RoboFile exec() command and tried to wrap it into `bash -c` because `nvm` is a bash function and not a real script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why is that?

When invoked with `-c`, bash runs as a *non-interactive* shell. The default interactive shell startup files (`/etc/bash.bashrc`, `~/.bashrc`) are not read. Even if you force `~/.bashrc` to be read, its body is likely not executed - the default Ubuntu one (copied from /etc/skel during account creation) for example includes the lines

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

which bypasses everything following.

You *could* force an interactive shell using `bash -ic`, however that may cause other issues depending on what else is in your `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
bash -ic nvm
```

Running bash as interactive shell **and** providing a command doesn't seem to comply with bash documentation but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to https://www.npmjs.com/package/n which works much better in this case.

It is a alterantive to `nvm` and does not need all those bash scripting. This is why it probably works also without the above problems.

`n` can be installed with the following command:

```
npm install -g n
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1250781)

Comment: Thanks, improved the answer a bit